# Difference of Two Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a quick question about finding the difference between two arrays. I found a chunk of JavaScript code that does what I want [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference) and modified it a bit:

JS

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  var newArr = [];
  var myArr = arr1.concat(arr2);

  newArr = myArr.filter(function(item){
     return arr2.indexOf(item) < 0 || arr1.indexOf(item) < 0;
  });

  return newArr;
}

diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

However, I'm not sure that I really understand what the filter function is doing here. Could anyone give me a clear explanation of how this works.

**Note:** I already know the basics of filter functions. I'm looking for a specfic explanation of this filter.

Comment: if item is not in `arr2` check if it's in `arr1`, if not in `arr1` either, return false, otherwise return true.

Comment: Thanks! This is starting to make more sense.

Comment: I don't like silly codes implying "hey look i have typed 2 characters less" . It should have been done like `arr2.indexOf(item) >= 0  && arr1.indexOf(item) >= 0;`

Comment: Are you saying replace the code:arr2.indexOf(item) < 0 || arr1.indexOf(item) < 0 with arr2.indexOf(item) >= 0 && arr1.indexOf(item) >= 0 ? This will create common items twice in newArr. That's not what he is looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
newArr = myArr.filter(function(item){
   return arr2.indexOf(item) < 0 || arr1.indexOf(item) < 0;
});
```

The `Array#filter` function iterates over each element of the newly made array from `concat` function (containing every element from `arr1` and `arr2` arrays).

If at least one of the conditions `arr2.indexOf(item) < 0` or `arr1.indexOf(item) < 0` is fulfilled (returns `true`) at some iteration, the `Array#filter` function *filters out* (returns) that specified (actually iterated) element.

In case, if the iterated element is both in `arr1` and `arr2`, the `indexOf` function will return it's index (which is higher than `0`) - the condition will return `false` (it's not smaller than `0`). We will receive then `false || false` which is `false` and that element won't be included in the `newArr` array, containing unique elements.

In case, if given element is only in one array (it doesn't exist in the second one - it's index will return `-1` - it will fulfill the `< 0` condition) - one of the conditions will return `true`, so the both conditions will become `true || false` which is `true` - given element **will be** included in the `newArr` array.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Filter is using a lambda to filter the list.

This essentially means that it executes the code between the { } and returns an array that meets the criteria.  Your criteria are that the index of the item is greater than 0 in both arrays which is essentially just saying it's in both arrays.

you can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Answer (score 0):

Easy way of thinking this is that filter function is internally creating an array.
The elements of this internal array are the ones that pass the condition in the callback function. This is possible since this decision is being made one element at a time in the callback function.

Condition arr2.indexOf(item) < 0 || arr1.indexOf(item) < 0 passes only for element 4 since at that time 4 is not present inside arr1. Since true is returned element 4 is added in the internal array. Ultimately 4 is returned in newArr.